# WordPress - Creating a Custom Loop with all categories displayed, but each category with seperate DIV, CLASS and ID

Tags: wordpress

I am fairly experienced with creating custom WordPress loops and such, but I have a requirement now that I need assistance on.

I need to create a WordPress loop that displays posts from all categories (that parts easy :-) ) however, each category needs to be encased in a DIV with a unique class and ID, with all of the posts for that category shown in that DIV.   This needs to happen to all categories, no matter how many there are, and no matter if new ones are added or old ones are removed.

If anyone can help me with this or provide an example, that would be grand :-)

Thanks so much
Zach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desired categories by doing:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories( $args ); ?>
```

Documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).

Then you can loop within `$categories`, using [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) create your `<div>` and do whatever you want with it. (including fetching all the posts that belongs to that category)

Those two links I gave you should be enough. But here is some pseudo code of what you may do:

```
$categories = get_categories( $args );
while($c in $categories):
    $posts = query_posts($c); 
    while($p in $posts):    
        <div></div>
    endwhile;
endwhile;
```

Comment: sure. don't forget to post your results.

Comment: Is there any chance you could expand further?  I have read through the documentation you linked too, and it all makes sense, though I am having trouble combining everything into a working query.  Even using your pseudo-code as a reference, I haven't been able to get anything working :-(